# Characterize the sphere using mean curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

We know the following result: if $\Sigma$ is a compact surface than
$$ \int_{\Sigma}H^2 \ge 4 \pi, $$
where with $H= \frac{1}{2}(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)$ we denote the main curvature. I have to prove that $\int_{\Sigma} H^2 = 4 \pi$ if and only if $\Sigma$ is a sphere $\mathbb{S}_R$. Now, if $\Sigma=\mathbb{S}_R $ then we know that $\kappa_1=\kappa_2=\frac{1}{R}$, so
$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}_R}H^2 d\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{S}_R}=\frac{1}{R^2}  \int_{\mathbb{S}_R} 1 \,\,d\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{S}_R} = \frac{4\pi R^2}{R^2}= 4 \pi .$$
How can I prove the other part of the proposition? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the other direction with a proof by contradiction?

Comment: @aGer Let's suppose that $\int_{\Sigma}H^2= 4 \pi $ but $\Sigma$ not a sphere. We know that $H^2 \ge K$, so $\int_{\Sigma}H^2 \ge \int_{\Sigma}K = 2 \pi \chi(\Sigma)$... Gauss-Bonnet?

Comment: Yes. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $K= k_1k_2$ and Gauss-Bonnet theorem implies $$ \int_S K
dS=2\pi \chi(S) $$

If $S$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ then $$ \int_S K dS=4\pi $$

And $$ H^2 = \frac{k_1^2+ k_2^2 +2k_1k_2 }{2} \geq \frac{|K| +
   K}{2} \geq K $$

Comment: Ok thank you! I have a little curiosity. We know that $H^2 \ge K$. If $\int_{\Sigma}K= 4 \pi$ can I deduce that $\Sigma $ has not hyperbolic points?

Comment: No. If $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to a sphere, it holds. Consider a sphere whose shape is like a heart balloon. So $K$ may be negative.

Comment: I'm sorry. If $\Sigma$ is a compact generic surface and $\int_{\Sigma} |K|= 4 \pi$, can I say that $\Sigma$ has no hyperbolic points?

Comment: If $\Sigma= T^2$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\int |K| = 4\pi $ ? This is true ?

Comment: $\int |K|= 2 \pi \chi(T^2)= -4 \pi $

Comment: @HeeKnowLee Only if $\Sigma $ is a sphere... true?

Comment: $\chi (T^2)=0$ so that $\int_{T^2} K =0$. But I can not convince that $\int_{T^2} |K|=4\pi$

Comment: But the connected sum of two $T^2$ has hyperbolic points... right? (Ok $T^2$ has only a hole)

Comment: $\int_{T^2\sharp T^2} K = -4\pi $ But it contains a point of positive Gaussian curvature so that $$ \int_{T^2\sharp T^2} |K| > 4\pi $$

Comment: And consider a torus obtained by rotating a circle. In this case $\int_{T^2} |K|=8\pi $ But if we deform $T^2$ then I can not know $\int_{T^2} |K|$.